Difference in implementation based on whether a calculated expression is returned directly or first stored in a variable then returned
Is there a difference between the following two implementations based on computational performance and memory consumption?
The difference is in storing an intermediate computation into a separate variable (S_corrected) first or not.
1)
def step(self, data_deriv: npt.NDArray) -> npt.NDArray:
        self.t += 1
        self.S = self.beta * self.S + (1 - self.beta) * data_deriv ** 2
        return data_deriv / np.sqrt((self.S / (1 - self.beta ** self.t)) + self.epsilon)

and
2)
def step(self, data_deriv: npt.NDArray) -> npt.NDArray:
        self.t += 1
        self.S = self.beta * self.S + (1 - self.beta) * data_deriv ** 2
        S_corrected = (self.S / (1 - self.beta ** self.t))
        return data_deriv / np.sqrt(S_corrected + self.epsilon)


Technically, the bytecodes of the two methods don't match. You can use dis.dis() to show you this. Under python 3.12, once you sort out the orderings and remove all the dupicated bytecode you are left with two additional instructions for the second method:
            228 STORE_FAST               2 (S_corrected)
            262 LOAD_FAST                2 (S_corrected)

Pedantically suggesting to me that the first method may be faster (though with the slightly different order of ops I'm not really certain). You could use timeit.timeit() to try to pick out a difference over a million calls but my intuition tells me that any observed difference would be spurious.
In any case, I feel the second is much more legible and I would use it.
